# Alternatives to UML interaction diagrams

Tags: architecture, diagram, uml

Any good alternatives to UML interaction diagrams?  They are nice, but I do not care that much about the order and I want to represent a lot of components on the screen.

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the order, I would suggest the possibility of using a UML Class Diagram. As this will present the classes/components of your project with the inheritance, relations and functionality of the classes, it doesn't give the order of events inside the system.

Here is an example for a Class Diagram:

[image]

A second possibility is going out from the UML world, and maybe using a mockup software to design the screen's actual look and components location. If that's what you need, [Here is an example for a tool](http://mockupscreens.com/).

Comment: Yes, I agree that class diagram is easier. If you have existing code then just reverse it and get a class diagram. Job done in 5mn.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to model objects but not the interaction between them an Object Diagram may be suited. You can even combine them with Class Diagrams. Classes alone are not suited to represent instance level structures.